# JavaScript string: get content of two standing next to each other pieces of content and wrap them together

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to create a small script that would wrap some parts of text from e.g. `<p>` tag like this one: `<p>... 'displayed text'[popup content] ...</p>` in a span wrapper.

The end result would look like this:

```
<span class='wrapper'>
  displayed text
  <span class='popup'>popup content</span>
</span>
```

At the moment I'm able to find and replace the text between apostrophes like this:

```
some_string.replace(/'(.*?)'/g,'<span>$1</span>');
```

But I would really like to wrap the `popup content` part first and then wrap it together with `displayed text` inside the `wrapper` element.

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - how about this?

```
some_string.replace(/'(.*?)'\[(.*?)\]/, "$1<span class='popup'>$2</span>");
```

Add a `\s*` between the two parts of the regex if they could be separated by whitespace:

```
/'(.*?)'\s*\[(.*?)\]/
```

Comment: It seems to select both the text between apostrophes  and brackets but the one in brackets gets replaced by `$2`

Comment: Oh, that's expected @AleksanderCiecierski because I forgot the capturing group.

Comment: Yes it works now. Thank you!
I really needded this so my HTML markup is cleaner and easier to edit.

I posted the comment before seeing that you've fixed it.